# Recommendation: RestKit or AFNetworking for Rest/Soap server

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, rest, soap

I need to write an app to deal with a Rest and SOAP API (both).

What do you think is better? `RestKit` or `AFNetworking`? Neither? Both frameworks work easily with REST. Can SOAP be a problem?

Ideas:

- RestKit ( + XML parser for SOAP cases)
- AFNetworking ( + XML parser for SOAP cases)

I've read that the latest version of `RestKit` is built on top of `AFNetworking`.

What do you think is a better practice?

Comment: Is it REST or is it SOAP?

Comment: I need to deal with a REST and SOAP API...

Answer (score 1):

RestKit is great at REST. Yes, it is built on AFNetworking so you have a lot of flexibility. The power of RestKit is in its ability to map from the received data to your data model. If you will be able to leverage this ability then it should be worthwhile.

Otherwise, you may want to look at things like [SOAPEngine](https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine) or [pico](https://github.com/bulldog2011/pico) (but they aren't as actively developed as RestKit or AFNetworking).